# Photoswipe: can't click play in edge browsers

Tags: javascript, video, photoswipe

I'm using Photoswipe to play  element and everything is working except in Edge browser.

I can se the video and the controls for the video but i can't click play. I can even see hover states on play button and i can also right click and play with no problem.

My guess is that there are some JS that prevents click inside this container
    
If i move my  outside that div, it can play fine.

How do i get it to work in Edge browser?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It turn out that i just had to use this bit of code in the option part :)

```
isClickableElement: function(el) {
    return el.tagName === 'VIDEO';
}
```